# How do you install Android Studio for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, android

I have looked around the web and tried to follow the official instructions (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) but the file I am meant to run called "Studio.sh" wont run? Thanks.

Comment: Why won't the file run? Doesn't it give you an error or something?

Answer (score 0):

The first time you run `studio.sh` do it using the terminal and not by double-clicking. (e.g. `./<path>/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`)

After it opens, you can go to Configure-->Create Desktop Entry to have a permanent shortcut to the application that you can use from there on.